# Unit test for a protected attribute Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, model

I'm working with Rails 3.2.2. And I have a devise model called user.

In my user model I set:

```
attr_protected :is_admin
```

(is_admin is a boolean attribute)

For test this property I made:

```
test "should not be able to change to admin" do
    user = User.create(:name => "Joaquim", :email => "example@test.com", :password => "123456", :is_admin => true)

    assert user.errors.get(:is_admin), "Cant change admin configuration"
end
```

When I run this test raise error:

```
  1) Error:
test_should_not_be_able_to_change_to_admin(UserTest):
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: is_admin
    test/unit/user_test.rb:44:in `test_should_not_be_able_to_change_to_admin'
```

What assert do I have to use for this test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
assert_raise(ExceptionClass) { .... }
```

In rspec you'd do

```
expect  { ... }.to raise_error(ExceptionClass)
```